# Color only one edge of div?

Tags: html, css

I have got a question. How can I color just one edge (top right) of a div?

```
<div id="div1"></div>
```

Comment: Please be a little bit more specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean for example Top Right border, you can do it this way

```
div{
     border-width: 1px 1px 0 0;
     border-style: solid;
     border-color: blue;
}
```

or

```
div{
     border-top: 1px solid blue;
     border-right: 1px solid blue;
}
```